# Xamarin GeoCordinate GetDistance Exception

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, gis

VS 2015, Xamarin Forms, PCL.

Found this..."https://ghuntley.com/archive/2016/01/05/geocoordinate-portable-released/" , and added it to my solution.

I added `System.Device` as a reference to the PCL project, so that I could use the `GetDistance` method of `Geocoordinate` class...https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinate(v=vs.110).aspx.

```
var sCoord1 = new System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinate(54.87623, -485.1765);
```

This gets exception...

> System.InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code in
>   System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinate:.ctor (double,double): method
>   body is empty.

I have no idea of what is causing this error.  IS it because I added System.Device to PCL project (Geo does not work without it)?

Comment: There are three overrides, this is one of them...GeoCoordinate pin1 = new GeoCoordinate();  This gets the same error.

Comment: I need help.  I do not know how to accept and up vote.  Please point me in right direction.